# Restrictive clause with a preposition

Tags: word-usage, punctuation, restrictive-clauses

I am not sure if this sentence is correct:

> The word, from which the Polish, Ukrainian and Czech verbs 'mówić', 'мовити', 'mluvit' descend, means 'to say'.

It is certainly a restrictive clause, but normally restrictive clauses are not set off with commas, and sense would be less clear if we remove the commas before and after the clause.

What should I change to get this sentence correct?

Comment: I don't see why it's restrictive. We are evidently talking about a specific word (that was probably mentioned in the previous sentence; it is marked with the determiner "the"). The "from which" clause simply provides more information about this word. If we are talking about a _specific_ word, we cannot restrict it any further.

Comment: Those commas are not the same; the first and the last serve to be the restrictive clause marker and the rest are just pauses.

Comment: @Cardinal Thank you for your remark, I've already corrected my question.

Comment: @tenebris2020 The word is implied. It is the only sentence in a response. Other words have already been mentioned in a dialogue, so the word 'word' is not specified otherwise than with the relative clause.

Comment: @GeorgePodkolzin It looks like a very artificial situation to me. It could probably help if you provided more information about this dialogue, and what kind of a "response" is it that only consists of this one sentence. (If it's a response to a question or something, _what_ was the question?) It could be a quiz where someone is supposed to guess which word is meant by the speaker. At any rate, the removal of the relative clause  would not make _the sentence_ less clear; it would just not provide sufficient information. It does not make the sentence deficient; it makes the utterance deficient.

Comment: In short, please read [this post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please). Not enough information in your post to answer your question.

Comment: "The word 'говорить' in Russian descends from a Proto-Slavic term that means 'to exclaim', while Polish, Ukrainian and Czech verbs 'mówić', 'мовити', 'mluvit' come from a word with the meaning 'tongue'."—

"The word, from which the Polish, Ukrainian and Czech verbs 'mówić', 'мовити', 'mluvit' descend, means 'to say' rather than 'tongue'."

Comment: @GeorgePodkolzin OK, this makes things clearer. Please always provide more context when asking questions. Don't expect people to read your mind over the Internet.

Comment: See, when you wrote, "It is certainly a restrictive clause" – it was not **at all** clear from the sentence itself that it is a restrictive clause. We _could_ imagine a text that says, "Now, let's discuss the word 'abcdef'. This word, which ... blah-blah-blah..., means 'uvwxyz'." So it's best that we don't have to _imagine_ anything because no additional context was provided. Context is really everything.

Comment: The word from which the Polish, Ukrainian and Czech verbs 'mówić', 'мовити', 'mluvit' **derive** means 'to say'.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a comma here but both are accurate grammatically:

- **The word from which** the Polish, Ukrainian and Czech verbs 'mówić', 'мовити', 'mluvit' derive means 'to say'.
- **The word, from which** the Polish, Ukrainian and Czech verbs 'mówić', 'мовити', 'mluvit' derive, means 'to say'.
- The person from who I learned the information had disappeared.
- The person, from who I learned the information, had disappeared.

If you make it restrictive by using commas, and you remove what is between them, the resulting sentence must make sense on its own. That said, I would not use commas.

You can write it as restrictive or not. And the word is derive here, not descend.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option would be to remove commas, which would serve as a visual clue that you want this to have a restrictive meaning ("that" and "which" are [sometimes interchangeable](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043635/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/that-or-which) in creating a restrictive sense).

Because if you want to keep the "from [?] .... descends", you cannot change "from which" to "from that". "From that" wouldn't work here. If you use a preposition, you need "which".

As the link above says, in AmE, "which" for restrictive clauses would generally be avoided, though not be considered incorrect. To avoid it, what you could also do is rephrase the whole sentence to say,

> "The word **that is the ancestor** of 'mówić', 'мовити', 'mluvit' means "to say" rather than "tongue".